# How to add an entry to mysqli array

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli, fputcsv

I am trying to add a single column at the beginning of a csv file using the code below:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $list = "'2795', $row";
    fputcsv($output, $list);
}
```

What am I missing? I know it's something simple. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you're using `mysqli` -  Use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` - You're mixing MySQL APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just join those values together:

```
$list = "'2795', $row";
```

Since `$row` returns a row result array, treat it as such, push that value inside:

```
$output = fopen('whatevername.csv', 'a+');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row[] = '2795'; // `$row` is an associative array
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
fclose($output);
```

Sidenote: This is a truncated code, so just make sure you have that file handle above this code that you presented.

Comment: This is excellent. I knew I was doing something minor wrong. My problem now is that it's adding it to the end of the file instead of the beginning. Any ideas?

Comment: @joshlsullivan what do you mean you want to add to be beginning? thats how it is. from top to bottom addition. if you want the results to be inverted, then you might want to sort it descending on the query instead,

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean I want '2795' to occur first in the array. Does that make sense?

Comment: @joshlsullivan oh, so you mean you want to push `2795` on the first position. then you should use `array_unshift($row, '2795');`

Comment: Beautiful! Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.